# Rails - Before_validation failing to generate item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here's my Model:

```
 validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
 validates :slug, uniqueness: true, presence: true

 # Callbacks
 before_validation :generate_slug

 # Methods
 def to_param
    slug
 end

 def generate_slug
    self.slug ||= name.parameterize
 end
```

On trying to create a new record, I'm getting the error message: "Slug can't be blank", via my browser.

That said - when testing using Ruby console, it works perfectly:

```
 Item.create! name:"Stack Overflow"
 ["slug", "stack-overflow"], ["name", "Stack Overflow"]
```

Not sure where to start, any ideas how to get this error to play nicely?

Comment: You have a validation on slug... so, shouldn't that be before_validation?

Comment: My mistake, I pasted a previous version - before_validation is present, and causing the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#creating-an-object), the `create` callbacks come after the `validations` callbacks, therefore at the time of validation your `generate_slug` method if not called yet, and your slug is nil.

You may want to use `before_validation` instead

---

**EDIT**

Perhaps your slug is not nil when in your before validation, could be due to database default value or form field posting, try this code instead

```
def generate_slug
  self.slug = name.parameterize if self.slug.blank?
end
```

Comment: Apologies, I uploaded a previous version. I am using before_validation, but still having the same error appear on trying to add a new record.

Comment: Seems to have solved the issue - thanks for the help!